# Given a graph $G=(V,A)$ with $|V|=n+1$ where $n$ of the vertices have increasing degree by one starting at one what degree is repeated on said graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've tried to solve the problem in the title and I can't find a way to do it. The exact problem is the following:

> Let $G$ be a graph with $n+1$ vertices. Let's suppose that for every
> vertex $i\in \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ its degree is $d(i)=i$. Then, what's the
> degree repeated on the graph?

I think that solving this is equivalent to solve for the last vertex's degree. I've solved this for a specific case and, if what i've done is right, in case the repeated degree was of a fixed value given any graph following that criteria then the value of the degree has to be the one I've obtained.

What I've done is the following:

Suppose you have $n$ vertices that follow the criteria given on the problem. Then, you could build a graph that connects $x_1$ to $x_2$ once leaving one edge for $x_2$ to be joint to another vertex. Then, you join $x_2$ with $x_3$, after that, the two remaining unassigned edges of $x_3$ you assign them both to $x_4$ and you assign both remaining edges of $x_4$ to $x_5$

[image]

This way, after analyzing the $n$-th term i got that the degree of the $n+1$-th term is $d(x_{n+1})=\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$

However, this only gives me the value of the repeated degree if its unique, I still have to prove that given a graph that fulfills all the above hypothesis the repeated degree is unique. This way I would have proven the problem

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me by showing me a different way to prove this or by showing me how to continue with the prove from this point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried counting the total number of edges and deducing $d(n+1)$ from that? Hint: Since each edge connects two vertices, one edge corresponds to two degrees.

Comment: @StiftungWarentest I tried that approach but I got to an expression like $2|A|=\sum_{i=1}^n+d(n+1) \Leftrightarrow d(n+1)=2|A|-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ where I can't solve for the LHS as I don't know the total number of edges

Comment: If you allow parallel edges, I don't think the last degree is uniquely determined. Are you sure that this is not just about simple graphs?

Comment: @DánielG., In the problem I saw it didn't say anything about simple graphs. However, my professor has forgotten to add the hypothesis of simple graphs more than once so it could be only about simple ones. How would you solve the problem if this hypothesis was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the graph is simple, as suggested in the comments.

We have $d(x_{n}) = n$. Since we have a simple graph, this means there is exactly one edge between the $n$th vertex $x_{n}$ and each of the other $n$ vertices.

What happens if we delete $x_{n}$ and all the edges coming out of it? Well, the degrees of each of the other vertices drop by $1$: the new degree of $x_{1}$ is $0$, the new degree of $x_{2}$ is $1$, and so on. Since $x_{1}$ is now an isolated vertex, we might as well delete it too.

So, we do the following:

- Take $G$, and delete $x_{1}, x_{n}$ and all the edges coming out of these two vertices. The remaining vertices are $x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_{n+1}$.
- Rename $x_{2}$ to $y_{1}$, $x_{3}$ to $y_{2}, \ldots, $ $x_{n-1}$ to $y_{n-2}$, and $x_{n+1}$ to $y_{n-1}$. Call this new graph $H$.

What can we say about $H$? Well, $H$ is a graph with two less elements than $G$. The degrees of the vertices $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{n-2}$ satisfy $d(y_{i}) = i$. Furthermore, the degree of the last vertex is $d(y_{n-1}) = d(x_{n+1}) -1$ (because we only deleted one edge, coming from $x_{n}$).

So, you can try induction!

Comment: With this same reasoning, instead of unduction could you reason recursively? you remuve vertex two by two untill you are only left with either the vertex $x_{n+1}$ or with said vertex and another vertex (the vertex $x_{(n+1)/2}$). In both cases you know the degree of the vertex you want to analize is either one or zero and you know how many edges you have removed from said vertex to get the the last iteration. Therefore, you get that $d(x_{n+1})=\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$